# Mysterious sounds of mail activities when using external loudspeakers

Tags: mail.app, usb

When I connect over USB to my MacBook AIR my external loudspeakers ("Philips multimedia 2.0 speakers SPA2201") I sometimes here immediately afterwards sounds of mail activity.

Mail.app is opened (as it is always) but there is no trace of activity to be found afterwards in it. I just hear the sounds: incoming mail (twice), outgoing mail (once).

My question is: why does this happen, could the loudspeakers connect over the internet to some distant server?

I have experienced it while using iTunes, and also VLC.

It is not systematic. It happens apparently when I have been without using the loudspeakers for some extended period of time.

[earlier formulation of my question erased, now that I understand it has nothing to do with iTunes]

Comment: Is Mail actually open when you open iTunes?

Comment: @IconDaemon sorry for delay. Yes, it is. It is very hard for me to diagnose accurately, as the phenomenon seems to pop up only after somewhat long periods (two weeks perhaps) of complete iTunes inactivity. So whenever I get interested again, I can't reproduce it. Another component of the problem is that I use external speakers connected to USB port plus audio connector. It seems I only notice the problem when connecting these speakers. Sorry about the confused information.

Comment: If it happens again, can you try recording it?

Comment: Just take out your iPhone and swipe to camera.  If it happens, use it, if not, don't and delete it.

Comment: @AwesomeUser I don't own an iPhone !

Comment: Then use something similar.  BTW Get an iPhone 6!